# Are there any alternatives to ICRA for self-regulated content labeling of websites?

Tags: whitelist, trust, labeling, parental-control, powder

I'm working with a gambling website that historically has labeled itself using the [ICRA Vocabulary](http://www.fosi.org/icra/#vocab) expressed with [RDF](http://www.w3.org/2004/12/q/doc/rdf-contentlabels.html#icra) and [PICS](http://www.w3.org/PICS/) labeling.  Its my understanding that these labels were interpreted by systems such as [Internet Explorer 6 Content Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-Content-Advisor-to-help-block-inappropriate-web-content) to block website access.

Unfortunately, the ICRA labeling scheme seems to be defunct as evidenced by the [ICRA Homepage](http://icra.org/).

> the ICRA labeling engine has been discontinued. While all current labels will continue to work with Internet content filters, the ICRA label generator, ICRA tools and Webmaster support will no longer be available.

The labels might still work, but its not possible to generate any new RDF files.  Additionally, PICS has been superseded by something called [POWDER](http://www.w3.org/TR/powder-dr/).

My question is:  Are there other self-labeling schemes that should be used to identify website content as containing language, violence, adult content, potentially harmful content such as gambling etc?  Do products like Netnanny and Cybersitter need these schemes, or do they block content based on url whitelists?

Update:
I did find some possible alternatives, but haven't yet assessed how useful they would be:

- [SafeSurf](http://www.safesurf.com/) is a rating system that covers various types of content
- [RTALabel](http://www.rtalabel.org/) is a pretty coarse grained system that identifies sites as "Restricted to Adults"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few lists that accept content provider self-identification:

- [URL BlackList](http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=submit)
- [Shalla Lists](http://www.shallalist.de/submissions.html)
- [OpenDNS Domain Tagging](http://community.opendns.com/domaintagging/)
- [My Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an ICR DNS TXT record with:

```
v=icr1;L=7;V=icr.chit.eu/check/
```

7 is "Adults Only"