# What is this pics-label tag doing?

Tags: html, meta-tags

(I'm going through an extremely basic website right now and trying to make it standards-compliant, although I'm pretty new to HTML.  I know this is a nubish question, but as I've been Googling for it, the only links I see are ones that will not let me see the forest for the trees.  I do not have time to spend two to three weeks going through irrelevant and low-level documentation to get one simple question answered that should be much easier to find simple, beginner-level charts and the like for.)

Take this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="pics-label" content='(pics-1.1
"http://www.icra.org/ratingsv02.html" l
gen true for "<domain>" r (nz 1 vz 1 lz 1 oz 1 cz 1)
gen true for "<domain>" r (nz 1 vz 1 lz 1 oz 1 cz 1)
gen true for "<domain>" r (nz 1 vz 1 lz 1 oz 1 cz 1)
gen true for "<domain>" r (nz 1 vz 1 lz 1 oz 1 cz 1))'>
```

Is this just saying, in an obsolete-but-still-used way, "Hey, my images are family-friendly, and no warning flags are necessary"?  Or is there something I should do to change it towards that end?

Why is the same text copied four times in a row (originally there were four images, by the way), and does this tag need to be changed if another domain is ever set to forward to this one?

Comment: ICRA labelling has been discontinued - see http://www.icra.org. In time, any support for it will be withdrawn and these tags will just be ignored. I'd remove them.

Comment: It's not going to hurt anything if I just take these out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You probably know this, but for all readers: [**PICS** has been superseded by **POWDER**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449786/1591669).)

What you got there:

- `pics-1.1` gives the version number of the PICS specification.
- `http://www.icra.org/ratingsv02.html` is the *service identifier* (which is a unique identifier for the chosen rating service).
- `l` is a shorthand for `labels`.
- `gen true for "…"` means that the following label can be applied to any URL that starts with `<domain>` (i.e., the URL is used as a prefix, similar to robots.txt’s `Disallow`).
- `r` is a shorthand for `ratings`, which gets followed by a parenthesized list of categories and values.

So your PICS `meta` element contains 4 *general labels*, where each label is an ICRA rating. Why 4? Probably because the site URL design requires it (but maybe those *general* labels were used here unnecessarily).

I have no idea what this rating is actually saying, as [the **ICRA** labeling engine has been discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449786/1591669).